# Is there a way to tell if my car uses USB 3?

Tags: usb, android-auto

I use Android Auto. Currently, I have a genuine USB 3.x cable (I think it's 3.0 not 3.1), but due to some issues with how far out of my phone the plug extends, I am considering alternatives. The problem is there are very, very few genuine USB 3.x cables with lower profile plugs, while there are a *ton* of USB 2.0 options.

I have seen some reports that AA works better with USB 3.x, so I don't want to artificially limit myself to USB 2.0. However, if the *car* doesn't support USB 3.x, I might as well use a USB 2.0 cable.

Is there any way to tell (using a non-rooted Android device) if I am actually getting USB 3.x speeds?

(I know there are some indicators, such as if the port is blue or has the "SS" logo, but I'd prefer an answer based on something that would work for any vehicle without having to rely on the port being properly marked, i.e. if the port is USB 3.x despite *not* being properly marked, how would I know?)

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual? I would think it would be prominent. Newest capabilities and benefits would be something the company would eager to advertise.

Comment: Perhaps, but much like port markings, I expect that to be a one-way test, i.e. while I might definitely determine it *is* USB 3.x, it wouldn't definitely tell me it *isn't*. Besides, even if I can find an answer some other way, I am really interested to know if there is any way to find the answer from my Android device. I know on a "regular" Linux distro, and thus probably on a rooted Android device also, there are tools to inspect the connection speed; I wan to know if there is something comparable for non-Rooted Android.

Comment: p.s. If it helps, using USB debugging (e.g. plug in to the car, then later use adb to inspect the device's logs).

Comment: USB 3 has more connectors. Therefore carefully examine the USB socket may get you the answer. USB 2.0 has only 4 connection pads, AFAIR USB 3.0 adds another 5. See for example this USB 3 plug: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/Connector_USB_3_IMGP6024_wp.jpg

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. However, I am still interested in an answer to the question as asked, even if it ends up being only for educational purposes .

Comment: Can you transfer files between the two – and does the "non-rooted Android device" support USB 3.0? If so, simply copy a large file and count how long it takes. Knowing the size, you can easily calculate. USB 2 is limited to 480 MBit/s. If you get more, it must be USB 3. Right?

Comment: @Izzy, I don't know of any way to transfer a file _to my car_. I'm looking for a method that doesn't rely on measuring transfer speed or on use of a desktop OS or rooted phone. For example, on desktop Linux I can use `lsusb`; is there anything like that I can run on a non-rooted Android device?

Comment: Ever tried `lsusb` from within a terminal app? The command is certainly there. Just tried it, but I had nothing suitable to connect. `lsusb --help` just says "List USB hosts/devices" – but while my computer is connected via USB (I ran that command via ADB), it's output was empty. Might look different with the car connected (a car drives, so it should be a drive #D).

Comment: @Izzy, at least my phone doesn't have `lsusb`. I suspect few if any android devices do; what would be the use case?

Comment: No idea. I was rather surprised, too – especially as the device I looked on was a cheap one running an Android Go stock ROM.